# Error 1146 in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to insert data into my table called 'user' but I'm getting this error. I've set the database properly.

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1146
>
> Table 'folwd.users' doesn't exist

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `username` = 'Pallavi123' LIMIT 1
```

> Filename: C:\wamp\www\PhpProject1\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

The table named `users` doesn't exist at all.

user_manager_controller:

```
public function register(){
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            //user is already logged in
            redirect('profile');
            }else{
            //init
            //$data['country_list']=$this->config->item('um_country_list');
            $data['username']='';

            $data['firstname']='';
            //$data['secondname']='';
            $data['lastname']='';
                        $data['email']='';
            //$data['dateofbirth']='';
            //$data['default_country']=$this->config->item('um_default_country');
            //load rules
            $rules=$this->config->item('um_register_rules');
            //default msg
            $data['msg']=$this->lang->line('um_form_msg');

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                //the user has submitted the form
                //get the user input
                $data['username']=$this->input->post('username');

                $data['firstname']=$this->input->post('firstname');
                //$data['secondname']=$this->input->post('secondname');
                $data['lastname']=$this->input->post('lastname');
                                $data['email']=$this->input->post('email');
                //$data['dateofbirth']=$this->input->post('dateofbirth');
                //$data['default_country']=$this->input->post('country');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);//check with the rules
                if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
                    //validation failed
                    $data['msg']=$this->lang->line('um_form_error');
                    $this->load->view('user_register_form',$data);
                }else{
                    //validation passed
                    $dbdata=array(
                        'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),

                        'firstname'=>$this->input->post('firstname'),
                        //'secondname'=>$this->input->post('secondname'),
                        'lastname'=>$this->input->post('lastname'),
                                            'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                                                'password'=>$this->input->post('password'),
                        //'dateofbirth'=>$this->input->post('dateofbith'),
                        //'country'=>$this->input->post('country')
                    );

                    $this->user_manager->register_user($dbdata);

                    $data['msg']=$this->lang->line('um_form_activate');

                    //render the view
                    $this->load->view('um_msg',$data);
                }
            }else{
                //render the view
                $this->load->view('user_register_form',$data);
            }
        }
    }
```

um_users_model

```
function register_user($dbdata){
    $this->db->insert('user', $dbdata);
    $this->db->last_query();
}
```

Comment: what is your table name.? user or users?

Comment: My tablename is 'user'.

Comment: The error is clear and obvious, Check if you have the table users exists under your `folwd` database.

Comment: First check if the table with the name `users` is exists on your database or not. And for your information the error is in SELECT query so check where you fetched the records

Comment: My database consists of a table named user and I checked the select query too..but the name is 'user' itself! I cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: 'user' and 'users' are different

Comment: Now when I've changed the tablename to 'users', the problem has changed. Actually I'm not getting why but a different table in a different database is being selected.

Comment: On your validation config, do you have any `is_unique` rules?

Comment: Yes..email. 'rules'   => 'trim|required|is_unique[users.email]|xss_clean'//valid_email